# Can one have a random effect in a mixed model without a corresponding fixed effect?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I struggling to understand whether it is possible to have random effect without the respectively fixed effect. 
For example, I use `lme4` to fit two models:

```
y ~ 1 + (1 + x | z)
```

and

```
y ~ 1 + x + (1 + x | z)
```

the random effect for `x` seems to be the same despite the fact that in the first model, there should be a random effect of `z` on the slope of `x`, but `x` doesn't seem to have a fixed effect (!). What am I missing?

Comment: Both models are possible. All random effects have mean zero, so in your first model you constrain the average (across `z`) effect of `x` on `y` to be zero. In the second model the average effect will be given by the fixed effect.

Comment: Thank amoeba. So this means that if the slope for the fixed effect is zero, the two models will be exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, I think so.